# Calculate expectation of a function of binomial random variables

Tags: statistics, expected-value, statistical-inference, binomial-distribution

Let be $X_1,...,X_n$ n independent random variables from a bionomial distribution $Bin(10,\theta)$, how can I calculate or approximate the following expectation:
$$
E\left[{1\over{1+\overline{X}_n}}\right]?
$$

Comment: Is $\bar X_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n X_j$?

Comment: Yes it is, I should have specified.

Comment: If $10\theta \ll 1$ you can approximate the expression by a Taylor series to obtain $E[(1+\overline X_n)] \approx 1 - \mu + \mu^2 + \frac{\sigma_X^2}{n}$

Comment: More generally you can expand $E[f(\vec x)]$ about its mean vector to obtain $$ E[f(\vec x)] \approx \frac{1}{1+\mu} + \frac{\sigma_X^2}{n(1+\mu)^3} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds an application of the delta method:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#:~:text=In%20statistics%2C%20the%20delta%20method,limiting%20variance%20of%20that%20estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20the%20delta%20method,limiting%20variance%20of%20that%20estimator).

By CLT:

$\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}-10\theta) \rightarrow_D N(0,10\theta(1-\theta))$

and calling $g(x)=1/(1+x)$

$\sqrt{n}(g(\overline{X})-g(10\theta)) \rightarrow_D N(0,10\theta(1-\theta)g'^2(10\theta))$

That is:

$\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{1+\overline{X}}-\frac{1}{1+10\theta}\right) \rightarrow_D N\left(0,\frac{10\theta(1-\theta)}{(1+10\theta)^4}\right)$

Comment: Don't you think it should be $N(0,{10\theta(1-\theta)\over{(1+10\theta)^4}})$?

Comment: yes you are right. modified.